# How to pass a variable set in Controller to Select Helper "value"?

Tags: phalcon

I have something like this in my Controller:

```
$this->view->userTagsComma = ($skills[0] == 'No Skills Set')?'':'"' . implode('", "', $skills) . '"';
```

And this generates something like `"Cooking", "Swimming"` when I echo this in View.

And in my View I have:

```
<?php echo Phalcon\Tag::select(array('user-skills-input', 
                                      TagsStandard::find("status = 1"), 
                                      "using" => array("name", "name"),
                                      "class" => "select-chosen",
                                      "type" => "text",
                                      "data-role" => "tagsinput",
                                      "value" => [],
                                      "multiple" => "multiple"
                                                        )); ?>
```

I want to pass `$userTagsComma` into `[]` in my select helper so how can I do it? I tried doing `"view" => [$userTagsComma]` in the select helper but it does not work.

Update: I tried putting in `"value" => ["Cooking", "Swimming"],` and this works. So not sure why passing in a variable with everything looking the same wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this within Controller `$this->view->userTagsComma = ($skills[0] == "No Skills Set") ? [] : $skills;` instead of imploding as it is already an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$this->view->userTagsComma = $skills[0] == 'No Skills Set' ? array() : $skills;

Phalcon\Tag::select(array('user-skills-input',
    TagsStandard::find("status = 1"),
    "using" => array("name", "name"),
    "class" => "select-chosen",
    "type" => "text",
    "data-role" => "tagsinput",
    "value" => $userTagsComma,
    "multiple" => "multiple"
));
```